# Looping to create tabs in tabsetPanel in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to use `lapply` to create multiple tabs in a `tabsetPanel` in Shiny based on this example: http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/creating-a-ui-from-a-loop.html. Below is my `app.R` code. When I run it, it doesn't create 5 tabs, nor does it print the name of each tab. What am I doing wrong?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("xxx"),
  sidebarPanel(),
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(id='t',
      lapply(1:5, function(i) {
        tabPanel(
          title=paste0('tab', i), 
          textOutput(paste0('a',i))
        )
      }) 
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  observe({
    print(input$t)
  })

  lapply(1:5, function(j) {
    output[[paste0('a',j)]] <- renderPrint({
      input$t
    })
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's a bit tricky, because `tabsetPanel` does not accept a list of `tabset` as an argument. You can use `do.call` to "unlist" arguments:

```
mainPanel(
    do.call(tabsetPanel, c(id='t',lapply(1:5, function(i) {
                  tabPanel(
                    title=paste0('tab', i), 
                    textOutput(paste0('a',i))
                  )
                })))
    )
```

Comment: dear @HubertL, , building on your solution here i m trying to create shiny app https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59079852/in-r-shiny-how-to-automatically-or-based-on-function-tabpanel-given-we-have-3
please check & advise on the error, thanks a lot

Comment: @HubertL Can the number of tabs (5 in this example) be defined by the user though?

Comment: @EmileZäkiev To have a dynamic number of tabs, generate the tabset with a `uiOutput()` and put the `do.call()` inside the `renderUI()`

Answer (score 3):

```
stack.app <- function(n = 5){

  library(shiny)

  ui <- pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("xxx"),
    sidebarPanel(
      verbatimTextOutput("show_selected")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput('my_tabs')
    )
  )

  server <- function(input, output, session) {

   output$my_tabs <- renderUI({
     ### Had to hicjack this from shiny to get it to work...
     shiny:::buildTabset(
       id = "t",
       lapply(1:n, function(i){
         tabPanel(title = sprintf("tt_%s",i),
                  HTML(sprintf("This is tab %s content", i))
         )
       }), paste0("nav nav-","tabs")) %>% (function(x){
         tags$div(class = "tabbable", x[[1]], x[[2]])
       })
   })

   output$show_selected <- renderPrint({
     sprintf("SELECTED TAB IS : %s", input$t)
   })


  }

  shinyApp(ui, server)

}
```

### Which results in:

[image: Here's the output]

Comment: Good job! However it's usually a good practice to avoid using unexported methods `:::` as they might not be maintained in next releases

Comment: Agreed @HubertL ; and after seeing your simpler solution I face-palmed. I try to avoid `do.call` at all costs... so I never even considered it.

Comment: why do avoid do.call, @CarlBoneri?

Comment: @EmileZäkiev just a matter of preference, no explicit reason. `lapply` reads more straightforward to me in this case, i rarely use `do.call`.